# Catch facebook init errors

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

How do I catch the errors, that are thrown when calling FB.init() function.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: conf.appId,
                autoLogAppEvents: false,
                xfbml: false,
                status: false,
                version: constants.fbVersion
            });
};
```

Sometimes when I call this code from a domain which is not registered with facebook, it throws  "*Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.*" .
This error is displayed in the console.
The question is how do I catch this error and do something when it is thrown?

Comment: why would you call this code from a domain not registered with facebook?

Comment: to test if I could catch the error from FB.init using try-catch

Comment: It is just one of many other errors which are printed by FB.init()

Comment: did you try with try/catch?

Comment: it does not work